# Show the ServerName for Get-WinEvent result in OutGridView?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

The script below to view the top 5 Error and Warning for the Directory Service Events in the past 7 days are working when executed in single server locally.

However, how to view the **server name** or **MachineName** column when executed against multiple AD servers remotely?

```
Get-ADDomainController -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty HostName | ForEach-Object {
    "Processing $($_) ..." | Write-Host

    Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $_ -FilterHashTable @{LogName = 'Directory Service'; Level = 1, 2; StartTime = (Get-Date).AddHours(-168) } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Select-Object -Property @{n = 'Server'; e = { $_.MachineName -replace ".$($env:USERDNSDOMAIN)",'' } }, 
                                    Id, 
                                    @{n = "ErrorType"; e = { $_.LevelDisplayName } }, 
                                    @{n = "Source"; e = { $_.ProviderName } }, 
                                    @{n = 'Message'; e = { $_.Message } } |
            Group-Object Server, ID, ErrorType, Source, Message |
                Sort-Object Count -Descending |
                    Select-Object -First 5 -Property Count, 
                        @{n = 'Server'; e = { $_.MachineName -replace ".$($env:USERDNSDOMAIN)",'' } }, 
                        @{n = "Id"; e = { $_.Group[0].Id } }, 
                        @{n = "ErrorType"; e = { $_.Group[0].ErrorType } }, 
                        @{n = "Source"; e = { $_.Group[0].Source } }, 
                        @{n = "Message"; e = { $_.Group[0].Message } }

} | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the computer name taken from the HostName straight away in your first ForEach loop

```
$machine = ($_ -split '\.')[0]
```

and use that in the Select-Object

```
Select-Object -Property @{n = 'Server'; e = { $machine } }
```

Then in the second Select-Object you can do

```
 @{n = 'Server'; e = { $_.Group[0].Server } }
```

or again

```
@{n = 'Server'; e = { $machine } }
```

Comment: That's great, I didn't think about that. many thanks @Theo. You're the best.